# Opencv detect all generic objects shapes on a table (birdview)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I would like to detect all kind of object shapes which are on a flat table. The table can have a gray, white or black surface color.

The objects can be any shape and can have different colors.

What is an efficient way to solve this problem?

**I have tried:**

1.) Convert to Grayscale, bilateral filter, canny edges then use findContours, also tried with adaptive threshold.

2.) OpenCV SimpleBlobDetector

**Original Picture**

[image: Original]

**Contours**

[image: Contours]

**Blob Detector**

[image: Blob]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in any case color is an issue you find the edges of the objects on the table using [adaptive threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html).

**Code:**

```
img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Jackson\Desktop\table.png', 1)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)

ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

adaptive_threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

img2 = img.copy()

_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(cv2.threshold(th3, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1], cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(img2, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

**Results:**

```
cv2.imshow('adaptive_threshold', adaptive_threshold)
```

[image]

```
cv2.imshow('img2', img2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An option could be the [Watershed Algorithm](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html#watershed). In the linked example coins are detected with this Algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If the objects are actually so varied in color then you can use the Hue channel of HSV color space.

```
image = cv2.imread('image.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv = cv2.split(hsv)
gray = hsv[0]

ret,binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

contours = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]

cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,0,255),2)
```

[image: result]